# Solve math equation mentally with algebra shortcut

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking to solve this equation mentally, with the following numbers, using an algebra shortcut.
$$a = bc + \frac{1}{2} dc^2$$
with
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
c &=& 10.204,
\\ d &=& -9.8,
\\ b &=& 100.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Can anyone think of a shortcut that would make solving this easier?

Comment: A downvote is useful only when accompanied by some comment explaining it :-).

Comment: Can someone please explain why this question was downvoted?

Comment: Xaav, To clarify, I did not do it. I was in fact requesting for such an explanation. Also, I think this question is interesting and within the scope of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $ Since $\rm\ \ d\:c\ \approx\ (0.2+10)\:(0.2-10)\ =\ 0.04-100\:,\ $ we conclude that

$\rm\ \ c\ (b+dc/2)\ \approx\  10.2 * (100 + (0.04-100)/2)\ \approx\ 10.2 * (50 + 0.02)\ \approx\ 510.204$

The above mental approximation is very close to the actual value - which is $\ \: 510.20404$